# What are the non-vanishing directions of $A_{a(b} B_{cd)} - B_{a(b} A_{cd)}$? ($A$ and $B$ symmetric tensors)

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, symmetry

**Question**

Consider two symmetric tensors $A_{ab}=A_{ba},\, B_{ab}=B_{ba}$ which are generally of full rank (non-degenerate, all eigenvalues non-zero but of general sign) and their tensor product under a particular symmetrization
$$(A_{a(b} B_{cd)} - B_{a(b} A_{cd)})\,,$$
where $(bcd)$ denotes the totally symmetric part of the tensor 
$$C_{(abc)} = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{\pi \in S_3} C_{\pi(a) \pi(b) \pi(c)}\,.$$
Now I would like to figure out how is the space of vectors $v^a$ restricted by the condition (Einstein summation assumed)
$$v^a (A_{a(b} B_{cd)} - B_{a(b} A_{cd)}) = 0\,.$$
I.e., *how large is the space of vectors $v^a$ fulfilling the above condition?*

(If it is of any help, I am mainly interested in dimension 4.)

---

**Attempts at solution/comments**

A tensor with three totally symmetric indices $b c d$ has 20 independent components (in dimension 4). This means that a condition of the type 
$$v^a D_{a(bcd)}$$
corresponds generally to twenty different conditions on the space of possible vectors $v^a$ and we thus have necessarily $v^a=0$.

(This would actually apply in any dimension because a 3-index totally symmetric tensor in dimension $n$ has $n+2 \choose 3$ independent components which is always $\geq$ than the critical $n$ conditions.)

However, if we were to only consider the condition 
$$v^a A_{a(b}B_{cd)}=0$$
it is unclear to me whether the fact that before symmetrization in $bcd$, we had $A_{a b} = A_{ba}$ affects the number of the resulting independent conditions on $v^a$. This symmetry **does not mean** $A_{a(b}B_{cd)} = A_{b(a}B_{cd)}$ and I am not quite sure how to approach it.

Then there is the antisymmetry with respect to the swapping of indices $ab \leftrightarrow cd$ which I am also unsure on how to handle. Normally, if we have a tensor $K_{(ab)(cd)}$ which is symmetric in $a\leftrightarrow b, c\leftrightarrow d$ and antisymmetric with respect to $ab \leftrightarrow cd$, it would have $${{n+1 \choose 2} \choose 2}|_{n=4} = 45$$ independent components.

But then again, the tensor $A_{ab}B_{cd} - A_{cd} B_{ab}$ possesses these symmetries but is antisymmetrized direct product of elements of two spaces. As we all know, the direct products of spaces always involve elements which are *not* expressible in this way (as a direct product of two elements from the respective spaces). Hence, the number of independent elements of $A_{ab}B_{cd} - A_{cd} B_{ab}$ will be surely smaller than that of a general $K_{(ab)(cd)}$.

Comment: -> As the end of the bounty approaches, I should just note that I will award the bounty to _any answer which at least gives a good attempt and a few pointers_. <-